# Calling a function defined inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am having a difficulty understanding Javascript-style function definitions.

I have a Websocket server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
wss = new WebSocketServer();

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('received: %s from client', message);
  })
  ws.send('hello client');
})
```

And I want to send a message to the connected clients when another function `importantEvent()` is called.

```
function importantEvent(message) {
  //send message to the connected client
  ws.send('hello client');
}
```

What is the good way of calling `ws.send()` inside `importantEvent()`?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking. What issue are you having calling `ws.send` inside of `importantEvent`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst it's a scope problem. ws is not defined there.

Comment: Ah. Is there any reason you can't save it to a global once it's available? `let wsGlobal; wss.on('connection', function (ws) { wsGlobal = ws; ... })` If it needs updating at times, you just update the global as well, and you attach all event handlers such as the `.on('message'` to the global save

Comment: Why don't you just create it inside `connection` event callback?

Comment: @Volodymyr it's not possible, this is forced by the SDK I use

Answer (score 2):

I use `EventEmitter` to similar things to avoid a strong module strength.

```
// eventManager.js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class EventManager extends EventEmitter {}
const eventManager = new EventManager();

module.exports = eventManager;

// websocket.js
var eventManager = require('eventManager');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
wss = new WebSocketServer();

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
...
})

function broadcast(data, filter) {
    wss.clients.forEach( ... // depends on library using to web-socket
}

eventManager.on('my-event', function (arg1, arg2) {
    broadcast({arg1, arg2})
});

// in any other files
var eventManager = require('eventManager');

eventManager.emit('my-event', 'hello', 'world');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of what clients you want to reach. In `wss.on('connection'...` event, the ws received by the function is the client that is connecting to the server in this event.

As you want send a message to all the clients connected, you need to use the [broadcast method](https://github.com/websockets/ws#server-broadcast)

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
wss = new WebSocketServer();

function importantEvent(message) {
    // Broadcast to all.
    wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send('hello client');
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks @javrd, this helps.

Is there a way of selecting a group of clients? Every message is not relevant to all of them and I can ask clients to (somehow) tell which type of messages they need.

Comment: Not sure with this library. With socketio you can subscribe the clients to a channel on connection event, and then later send a message to a channel to reach only the clients you have subscribed to it. You can try use the clients objects that we are iterating here, filtering them by ids or something. Also, this code is just a copy paste from the github readme, take into account that it probably doesn't work as it is now and you will have to work a little on it.